# AWS S3 SDK Linker issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

Hi I'm using the AWS SDK for a sample application. Specifically I', trying to implement an S3 bucket and object view. I've added the necessary classes, headers, and frameworks. In addition I've checked the build settings and all necessary frameworks are linked. These are the errors I get.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AmazonClientManager", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  objc-class-ref in AddBucketViewController.o
>
>  objc-class-ref in AddObjectViewController.o
>
>  objc-class-ref in BucketList.o
>
>  objc-class-ref in ObjectListing.o
>
>  objc-class-ref in ObjectViewController.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.

The AmazonClientManager class is something we include our samples, so it sounds like you've copied some code from our samples into your project.  You'll want to make sure those files are added to the **Compile Sources** of the **Build Phases** for your project as shown in the screen shot below.

[image: shot of]

Comment: I added that but then 2 more errors were given. Consequently I had to add the SimpleDB, SNS,and SQS frameworks to the project. Now all is well. Thanks!